# Update secret parameter in Jenkins Job

Tags: api, jenkins

I have a lot of free-style jobs in my Jenkins instance. I create them with Jenkins API (generate XML-file with configuration and post them by "http://my-jenkins-instance:8080/createItem?name=JobName").
There is one problem - I can not generate value in secret fields. For example, I want such a config:

Inject passwords to the build as environment variables -> Job passwords.
And I need to set `123` to `Password` field.
I can not do this through XML because it appears decoded in XML. Something like this: `{AQAAABAAAANwHq0hsSF6...}`

[I want to set the value to this parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9ebB.png)

So my questions are:

1. Can I get the decoded value of a plain password through some API? So I could send `123` and get `{AQAAABAAAANwHq0hsSF6...}` back.
2. If not, can I set secret value some other way? I can only think of using Selenium but it is too slow (comparing to API).

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.
I can set the value as a plain text: `<value>123</value>`, create or update a job. Then I need to disable and enable the job.